# Application failed to start due to port already in use but still Kafka Consumer still start consuming the messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have Spring Boot application and we are using Spring cloud stream kafka binder version 3.2.6 for kafka connectivity. What we observed is , Application is failing to start due to error "port already in use" but still Kafka Consumer start consuming the messages. And due to that messages are failing to process and going into dlq as we are getting error Application Context has not been refreshed yet. We are using default Spring boot Tomcat server. Below are the complete errorstack

How do we make sure that Spring Kafka consumer should not start consuming the messages if Spring boot application is not fully initialized?

Below Exception occurred on application startup.

> Exception occurred during context initialization port 65000 already in use

> Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.getTargetBean(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:371) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:336) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1058) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1652) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.destroy(DefaultBinderFactory.java:120) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1163) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1156) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:596) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
> at com.aa.ve.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:52)

Below Exception occurred while Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder StreamBridge trying to send the message to the topic

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@25da615a has not been refreshed yet
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1141) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1171) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.addInterceptors(StreamBridge.java:325) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.resolveDestination(StreamBridge.java:300) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:217) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
> at com.de.ve.CustomPublisher.send(CustomPublisher.java:78)

One of the option I choose to avoid this issue is I changed the consumer auto-startup property to false.

```
spring:
     cloud:
         stream:
            bindings:
              consumer-1:
                 consumer:
                    auto-startup: false
```

Written CustomListener that implements ApplicationListener
and in onApplicationEvent method I changed the endpoint state to "STARTED". Like below.

```
public class CustomListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

   BindingsEndpoint endpoint; 

   public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event){
       endpoint.changeState("consumer-1",BindingsLifecycleController.State.STARTED)
   }
}
```

Is this the right option or there any other alternatives way to handle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What server are you talking about? Please be more specific

Comment: We have Sprint Boot application and for Kafka connectivity I am using Spring Cloud stream Kafka binder 3.2.6

Comment: You did not answer my question. How can one possibly know which server/port you are asking about when you have not shared any details, stack trace. . .

Comment: I have updated the question with stack trace. Please check if that help. Actually what I am trying to understand is why Spring Cloud stream Kafka Binder is trying to consume the messages even if Application has failed to start.

Comment: You have `com.de.ve.CustomPublisher.send(CustomPublisher.java:78)`. I don't know what that is and how it is implemented but it is your code that sends a message using StreamBridge. Perhaps you can produce a small sample that reproduces the issue so we can look